# How do I control which shard/split a record goes to in Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

When adding new records to a Cloud Spanner Table, how do I determine which shard/split this row is going to?
This would be especially relevant in adding records with a foreign key value, and I would like to ensure it lives in the same place as the parent row which it references.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Google Cloud Spanner does all that for you in the background.

Instead of Foreign Keys, Cloud Spanner calls them "Interleaves".  When inserting a new record into a table with a foreign key, Spanner will do its best to make sure the new record lives in the same Split as its Interleave parent record.  There are corner cases which this does not happen, but Spanner is constantly re-organizing its splits, so even if a new record does not live in the same Split as its Interleave parent record, it eventually will.
It is also inferred by this regular re-organization of splits that even if you could decide which Split a parent record and all its children records live in, Spanner might decide at any time they are best existing in a completely different Split.